# Get data based on unique field mongodb during pagination

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Sorry if the title is wrong but here is what i am trying to do, let's say i have the objects :

```
{"_id": "anyID0", "contentID": "content1", "value": "any value", "at": 10} 
{"_id": "anyID1", "contentID": "content1", "value": "any value", "at": 9} 
{"_id": "anyID2", "contentID": "content2", "value": "any value", "at": 8} 
{"_id": "anyID3", "contentID": "content3", "value": "any value", "at": 7}
```

I would like to perform a query that :

- Get 20 of these objects using `limit`
- Get them sort by `at` `descending`
- If the query matches an already queried `contentID`, then skip it without considering it as a result.

As an example with the above objects :
If i use `query.limit(2)` where `query` is the one i am asking here, i would like the result to be :

```
{"_id": "anyID0", "contentID": "content1", "value": "any value", "at": 10} 
{"_id": "anyID2", "contentID": "content2", "value": "any value", "at": 8}
```

So it has skipped the `{"_id": "anyID1", "contentID": "content1", "value": "any value", "at": 9}`

I would like to know if it's possible without aggregation and / or if it would have correct performances.

I also would like to see working examples, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if it's possible without aggregation and / or if it would have correct performances.

No it's not possible.

Unfortunately there is no efficient way to achieve this in Mongo. You'll have to first `$group` all documents by contentId, then we'll have to sort them again as `$group` does not preserve order.

At this point we'll be able to paginate with `$skip` and `$limit`, obviously as you can tell this is very inefficient.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$contentID",
      first: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "first._id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$first"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d0ynoDF58OS)

If you'd be open to either a schema does or updating another collection this would be best, for example you could create another collection which will only contain the first document. this will allow easy pagination, it is also somewhat easy to maintain this on updates, but if you have a lot of deletions this approach is also not optimal and I'd recommend you go for a schema change.

Comment: Thank you very much, my scheme is that i am querying the comments of user's publication in a collection, and each comment has the publication_id field. 
The above question is about retrieving the publications where the current user has commented, ordered by date descending. 
If i don't use the above approach, if i have commented 30 times the same publication, the pagination will return only 1 publication with limit 20 for example. 
I will try to find a better scheme for this or not implement this feature for now, or as you suggested maybe adding a flag on the first comment.

Comment: I am going for the solution by adding a bool `first` to tell if the comment is the first made by any user on each publication. Thanks for your fast answer to lead me to a better direction !